# React: passing data between sibling without causing a rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem:
I got an App (A) and a lot of children (B, C, etc).
Now I would like to pass a value from B to C but without any rerender of the whole App. How is this possible?

```
A (Parent)
    |---- B (Child)
    |---- C (Child)
    |---- D (Child)
    |---- E (Child)
    |---- F (Child)
```

I tried to use `useContext` or a simple callback but in each case the state is hold in `A`, which, by change makes my whole App to rerender. Any Idea on how to make ii in a proper way?

Comment: Why not use Redux? Redux is invented to solve that problem.

Comment: Will rerender cause any problems?

Comment: Read about memoiziation in React

Comment: Agree with @wang Is the app re-rendering causing an issue? If not then you may simply be prematurely optimizing. If rerendering is an issue, then react has tools available to help memoize values, functions, and components. [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) can certainly help hint to react that a functional component should *not* rerender.

Comment: @Ahmad: well, first wanted to learn pure react, then redux. Will do my next app in redux ;-).

Comment: @wang: yes, when the whole app is rerendering, than it causes problems, like my list of favorites closes, etc.

Those are small issues, but annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> shouldComponentUpdate

to avoid this type of scenario. It works for both props and state.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 return this.props.somevalue != nextProps.somevalue;
}
```

Check if there is any new props passed to the child. If not then the component wont re-render. But avoid using too many children and come up with a better design structure.

**Edit:**

You can use

> PureComponent

as it implements shouldComponentUpdate by default. As mentioned in the doc:

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference
> between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement
> shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a
> shallow prop and state comparison.
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result
> given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a
> performance boost in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior in React is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior. But when you want to block the re-render of component when the state change and some value from state are passed to child component as props you can take advantage of `shouldComponentUpdate`

> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

Lean more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

To block the re-render you should should perform a check in the `shouldComponentUpdate` to ensure that the previous props and the current one aren't the same. If they are the same. you block the re-render by return `false` and if they are different you return `true` which will trigger the re-render.

Or you can use memo

Answer (score 1):

You can use **React.memo(component)**
This is saved your component from unusual renders.
read this one https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo